# Establishing shared connection using node-mysql in node-expess app

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

Currently I dont use connection pooling on my settings since i only have 1-4 users in the application.

According to the [doc](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#establishing-connections) this is the recommended way.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }

  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
```

Now, what i did was export the connection object and shared it to other api resources.

On **db.js** file

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... });

module.exports = connection;
```

On **api.js** file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const conn = require('./db');

router.post('/create', function (req, res) {
    connection.query('INSERT ...', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        // connected!
    });
});


router.post('/update', function (req, res) {
    connection.query('UPDATE SET ...', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        // connected!
    });
});
```

**AND SO ON** the same goes to the other api resources that was omitted in these examples..

What is the drawback in this connection design?

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I'm wrong. I think, even though you export the connection object, you're still managing the connection one by one.

> Opening and maintaining a database connection for each user, especially requests made to a dynamic database-driven website application, is costly and wastes resources
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)

And from the same [doc](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections),

> This is because two calls to pool.query() may use two different connections and run in parallel

So the best way is to use pool for managing the connections

> Connections are lazily created by the pool. If you configure the pool to allow up to 100 connections, but only ever use 5 simultaneously, only 5 connections will be made. Connections are also cycled round-robin style, with connections being taken from the top of the pool and returning to the bottom.

Hope that helps.